# Why does $\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{ 1}{  n^2  \log (n) }$ converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

The way I see it you can compare

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{ 1}{  n^2  \log (n) } < 1/n$$

$1/n$ is a $p$-series in which $p = 1 \leq 1 $

So $1/n$ diverges.

Thus $\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{ 1}{  n^2  \log (n) }$ diverges.

Comment: You make a mistake, you are basically saying that since $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{ 1}{  n^2  \log (n) } < \infty$ it has to be infinite.... But any number is less than infinity...

Comment: No, that's not how [the comparison test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_test) works.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As $\ln(n) > 1$ for $n > e$, $\frac{1}{n^2 \ln(n)} < \frac{1}{n^2}$. The latter is known to converge.

Comment: That makes sense.  Can you tell me what the flaw in my argument was ?  It still seems like it should work

Comment: Showing that $\sum x$ is bounded by a divergent $\sum y$ says nothing about the convergence of $\sum x$. All series are bounded by divergent ones. The argument is only useful if $y$ converges or $x > y$ instead.

Comment: actual   flaw is that you have compared to $1/n$

Comment: @ordinary the flaw in your argument is that you do the comparison using the wrong inequality. To show something diverges with comparison, you need to show that it is at least as large as some divergent series, not smaller than it.

Comment: @ordinary $1/n$ diverges does not imply the series diverges; if your inequality was > then you can say that

Comment: ah I understand now.  Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Integral test for convergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence): Since 
$\frac d{dt}\text{Ei}(-\log t)=\frac d{dt}\text{li}(\frac1t)=\frac1{t^2\log(t)}$, we get
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\int\limits_2^\infty \frac1{n^2\log(n)}dn&=&\text{Ei}(-\log n)\Biggr|_{2}^\infty&<&\infty\\&=&\underbrace{\text{Ei}(-\log \infty)}_{=0}-\text{Ei}(-\log 2)\\
&=&-\text{li}(\frac12)\\
&=&-\int_{0}^{1/2}\frac{dn}{\ln n}&&\hskip0.7in (*) \\
&=&0.378\dots&<&\infty
\end{eqnarray}
$$ your sum converges:
$(*)$ is finite, since $\underbrace{\text{li}(1)}_{-\infty}<\int_{0}^{1/2}\frac{dn}{\ln n}< \underbrace{\text{li}(0)}_{=0}$ and $0<\frac12<1.$